# Proving limit for the root of a function

Tags: limits

I am stuck on some homework questions but don't want to post the question directly, so i can work it out by myself but I will post a general version of it.

> Given $\lim_{x \to q}(f(x))^{\frac{1}{n}}) = L^{\frac{1}{n}}$
>
> Prove $\lim_{x \to q}(f(x))=L$

I am not sure where to even start with this, I know I need to do something with the first limit to generate $\epsilon$ and $\delta$ to feed into the proof for the second limit.

Again this is homework and I want to work it out myself but I need some hints please.

Thanks

Comment: $\lim_{x\to q} g(x) = A$ and $\lim_{x\to q} h(x) = B$ then $\lim_{x\to q} g(x)\cdot h(x) = A \cdot B$

Comment: or use $a^n-b^n=(a-b)(a^{n-1}+\dots+b^{n-1})$ and find a bound for the second factor

Comment: Sorry, I'm still really struggling with this could you elaborate

Answer (score 0):

One way to solve this is to instead prove that
$\lim_{x\rightarrow q} f(x) = L$ implies $\lim_{x\rightarrow q} (f(x))^n = L^n$, and then replace $f$ and $L$ by $f^{1/n}$ and $L^{1/n}$ respectively.

So, assume that $\lim_{x\rightarrow q} f(x) = L$. Also, assuming that $L\ge 0$ is finite, this implies that there exists a $\delta_1>0$ such that $|x-q|\le \delta_1 \Rightarrow |f(x)-L|<L$, such that $|f(x)|\le 2|L|$. We now factorize $f^n-L^n$ giving
$$ |f^n-L^n|=\left|f-L\right|\left|f^{n-1}+f^{n-2}L+\cdots fL^{n-2}+L^{n-2}\right|\le|f-L|\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\left|f^{n-1-k}L^k\right|$$
where the inequality follows from the triangle inequality (i.e. $|a+b|\le |a|+|b|$). For $|x-q|<\delta_1$ we then have
$$|f^n-L^n|\le \left|f-L\right|\left|L\right|^{n-1}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} 2^k< \left|f-L\right|\left|L\right|^{n-1}2^n$$
If we now let $\delta_2=\epsilon(\left|L\right|^{n-1}2^n)^{-1}$ and set $\delta = \min\{\delta_1,\delta_2\}$ we get that
$$|f^n-L^n|<\epsilon $$
whenever $|x-q|<\delta$, proving that $\lim_{x\rightarrow q} (f(x))^n = L^n$.